# Typescript Parameters get types for methods that allow either one or two arguments e.g. Element.scrollBy

Tags: typescript

For example, how can I get the options parameter of scrollBy() method?

```
Parameters<Element["scrollTo"]>
```

only returns `[x: number, y: number]` and not `options?: ScrollToOptions`

```
scrollTo(options?: ScrollToOptions): void;
scrollTo(x: number, y: number): void;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28789) issue and TS [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

> When inferring from a type with multiple call signatures (such as the type of an overloaded function), inferences are made from the last signature (which, presumably, is the most permissive catch-all case). It is not possible to perform overload resolution based on a list of argument types.

`Parameters` always returns last call signature

In this case it worth using :

```js
const foo:Element["scrollTo"]=(...args:unknown[])=>{

}
```

[image]